# Getting object coordinates from camera

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I've implemented a camera in Java using a position vector and three direction vectors so I can use `gluLookAt();` moving around in `ghost mode' works fine enough, but I want to add collision detection. I can't seem to figure out how to transform my position vector to coordinates in which OpenGL draws my objects.

A rough sketch of my drawing loop is this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
camera.setView();
drawer.drawTheScene();
```

I'm at a loss of how to proceed; looking at the ModelView matrix between calls and my position vector, I haven't found any kind of correlation.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out by reviewing http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter03.html again. To get from eye space (camera) to object space, you have to multiply that vector with the inverse of the ModelView matrix, or in code:

```
Vector4f vpos = new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 1); 
// (0,0,0,1) because it's relative to the cam
float mv[]=new float[16];
ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64);
temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer());
temp.asFloatBuffer().get(mv);
Matrix4f m4 = new Matrix4f();
m4.load((FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer());
m4.invert();
vpos = Matrix4f.transform(m4, vpos, vpos);
```

Comment: Please don't abuse OpenGL as math library. FYI: All those matrix function have been removed from OpenGL-3 upwards. You should do the matrix stuff yourself or use a math library. Most physics libraries also do that matrix stuff, so you get both: The math and collision detection.